Генерация QR кода с текстом
Есть код на python, генерирующий QR код:
import qrcode

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=10,
    border=4,
)

qr.add_data('Какой-то текст')
qr.make(fit=True)

img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
img.save("qrcode.png")

Проблема заключается в том, что на некоторых устройствах текст, который содержится в QR коде, попадает автоматически в поисковую строку браузера. Могу ли я, на уровне кода, настроить QR код так, чтобы при считывании с любого устройства текст, который в нём хранится, воспринимался именно как текст и открывался через текстовые редакторы для любого устройства, без действий со стороны пользователя?

qr-код хранит лишь текст, который вы в него "зашили", а как будет этот текст обрабатываться на устройстве пользователя зависит только от устройства и ПО, с помощью которого производится сканирование

@KirillLanskoy, с чего бы? Как написано выше это зависит от приложения-читалки кодов
